# How to preselect the spinner in custom adapter class?

Tags: android

I have created a spinner with a custom Adapter. I am trying to the preselected items on the following spinner. I am not able to get the position of the text.

This is my class:

```
public class Spinner {
    private String id;
    private String name;

    public Spinner(String id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if(obj instanceof Spinner){
            Spinner c = (Spinner )obj;
            return c.getName().equals(name) && c.getId().equals(id);
        }

        return false;
    }

}
```

And I am setting the data in the spinner through :

```
ArrayAdapter<Spinner> vehicle_type_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, vehicle_type_list);
spinner.setAdapter(vehicle_type_adapter)
```

How can I get the position of the name from it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can set AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener:

```
  spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(
            new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Spinner currentItem= vehicle_type_list[position]
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                }
            }
    );
```

Comment: I want to preselected when the activity loads. This won't work in my case